# A simple UTF-8 adaption partially works in Knuth's TeX and do nothing in LuaTeX

Tags: macros, luatex, unicode, plain-tex

Once more time I am (frustratingly losing time: true joke!) trying to use better TeX primitives. The next snippet doesn't work as expected in Knuth's Tex. The lower case version simply swallow the character.

```
\catcode"C3=13 % catcode for first bit
\catcode"A7=11 % and second ones for
\catcode"87=11 % unicode ç Ç

\def^^c3#1{%
  \begingroup
  \def\arg{#1}%
  \def\upper{^^87}% work only in original TeX engine
  \def\lower{^^A7}% not work in both cases
%   
%
  \ifx \upper\arg \c C%
  \else
  \ifx \lower\arg \c c%
  \fi\fi
  \endgroup
}

caçhaca e Çassi.

ca\c chaca e \c Cassi. %expected macro expansion
\end
```

Using LuaTeX engine the things get worse: the `ç` and `Ç` are completely ignored.

I would like to understand each of these unexpected results.

Comment: LuaTeX is a native UTF-8 engine, you are using bytes ...

Comment: So when was the syntax lost in LuaTex or bad applied by me? I can't get at first glance what LuaTex's UFT-8 supports really means.

Comment: why do you have the internal, definitions of `\def\arg` etc then compare with `\if` not `\ifx` ????? having `\begingroup` and definitions will destroy any kerns or ligatures in the font specified for `ç` You could look how latex defines these working for multiple encodings and engines and without breaking font-specified kerns

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I assume this is purely academic, and if we are dealing with bytes then `\if` is fine ...

Comment: @JosephWright well `\ifx` would be a whole lot safer than `\if` if two tokens end up in `\arg` but conversely if `\if` is used you could remove all the internal `\def` and the `\begingroup` so not break kerning, so it's not really academic, so much as a pointer to a more usable definition

Comment: All of You are right.

Answer (score 6):

The issue when running with Knuth's TeX or another 8-bit TeX (e.g. pdfTeX) is that `\def\lower{^^A7}` stores literally `^^A7` in `\lower`: you want `\def\lower{^^a7}`. It will then work: you have a stored byte as expected.

In LuaTeX (or XeTeX), input is not read as bytes but as Unicode codepoints: this means that `ç` and `Ç` are single tokens which have their own catcodes.

Comment: So, writing \catcode`\Ç=13 \defÇ{\c C} (and variations)  resolves the problem in LuaTex. Now I've understood the meaning of saying "LuaTex has UTF-8 support". Token is not defined by byte, but by character.

Comment: @DanielBandeira Well I'd just pick a font which has Ç as a character, but yes that would work

Comment: Tell me, please, how to easily make a font reachable by the engine.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* use `\def\lower{^^a7}` in LuaTeX (but note the lowercase `a`):

```
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)
 restricted system commands enabled.
**\relax

*\def\lower{^^a7}\show\lower
> \lower=macro:
->§.
<*> \def\lower{^^a7}\show\lower
```

But the main problem is that LuaTeX *never* sees `C3A7` when the input is `ç`, because it doesn't read byte-by-byte, but codepoint-by-codepoint. If the file is UTF-8 encoded, then upon seeing `C3A7`, LuaTeX transforms it into `U+00E7` and this is what's passed to the eyes for tokenization. So your active `^^c3` character is never seen.

Well, you *can* use the legacy methods, but I see no reason to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}

\catcode"C3=13 % catcode for first bit
\catcode"A7=11 % and second ones for
\catcode"87=11 % unicode ç Ç

\def^^c3#1{%
  \begingroup
  \def\arg{#1}%
  \def\upper{^^87}% work only in original TeX engine
  \def\lower{^^a7}% not work in both cases
%   
%
  \ifx \upper\arg \c C%
  \else
  \ifx \lower\arg \c c%
  \fi\fi
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

ç Ç

^^c3^^a7 ^^c3^^87

\end{document}
```

[image]